# How to make your IP address stable?

Tags: azure, networking

**The Problem**
I'm trying to understand more about networking, firewalls, and IP ranges to help me solve a few real-life problems. The problem I ran into is that the SQL server I'm connecting to has a firewall which can list individual IP's or IP ranges, but my ISP changes my IP fairly frequently, which means that whitelisting my current IP is a temporary solution and I'll eventually be disconnected.

**The Question**
If I wanted to stabilize my IP and make it so that it comes from a predetermined range (or even a single static IP), would the best way of doing that be to make a virtual network that I can VPN into that has a specified range of IP's? Or is there any easier solution?

**Details**
I'm interested in the answer at a broad level, but the specific database I'm connecting to is on Azure. Hence, my thought process would be to create a Virtual Network and and a Virtual Network Gateway, which I would connect to using a standard VPN connection tool like Hamachi or Open VPN. I'm assuming then that I could open up a tool like PGAdmin and connect to the database, because the database would consider the incoming connection to be from the IP range that I've whitelisted and that the Virtual Network sits on. Is this accurate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you trying to connect to a MySQL database over the Internet to a computer that's on a personal or home ISP IP address?

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to connect to an Azure cloud SQL database that has a firewall and is only open to whitelisted IP's.

Comment: Does the Azure cloud SQL database have multiple IP addresses?

Comment: The SQL database operates on one IP, but it allows incoming connections from multiple IP addresses and you can even specify IP ranges are that are allowed.

Comment: If the Azure cloud SQL database has one IP address, you can connect to it using the same JDBC connection string from any other IP address.  As you've stated, on the database server you can specify the IP address ranges that are allowed to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, if there is a public IP range from your on-premise outbound traffic, you just need to whiltelist the IP list on the firewall of Azure SQL database server. It is a simple method.

If you want to block the public endpoint from on-premises machines, you can use private endpoint for Azure SQL database. Read [On-premises connectivity over private peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview#on-premises-connectivity-over-private-peering) for more details.

> With Private Link, customers can enable cross-premises access to the
>   private endpoint using ExpressRoute, private peering, or VPN
>   tunneling. Customers can then disable all access via the public
>   endpoint and not use the IP-based firewall to allow any IP addresses.